# Generate image on-the-fly using FLask and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I would like to plot an image without having to save it in a static folder.

I've got an example posted here by user Messa working just fine:

```
import io
import random
from flask import Response
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot_png():
    fig = create_figure()
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

def create_figure():
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = range(100)
    ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]
    axis.plot(xs, ys)
    return fig
```

Then in the HTML file:

```
<img src="/plot.png" alt="my plot">
```

The result is perfect. I get the image on the fly.

Now I would like to use some parameters like this:

```
@app.route('/<x_values_source>/<y_values_source>/plot.png')
def plot_png(x_values_source, y_values_source):
    fig = create_figure(x_values_source, y_values_source)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

def create_figure(x_values_source, y_values_source):
    x_values = function_that_returns_x_values_set(x_values_source)
    y_values = function_that_returns_y_values_set(y_values_source)
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    axis.plot(x_values, y_values)
    return fig
```

But of course It doesn't work. I'm quite new to Python and I'm still learing a lot of things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

To pass parameters in, it's best to not prefix them to the URI, since that might confuse Flask's route decoding. Instead, if you form the URL like

```
/plot.png?x=1,2,3,4&y=100,200,300,400
```

you can pick the args up via `request.args`. They'll come in as strings, so you'll need to seperate and convert to ints (or floats, if you're using real numbers)

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot():
    try:
        x_values = [int(x) for x in request.args.get('x','').split(',')]
        y_values = [int(y) for y in request.args.get('y','').split(',')]
    except:
        # malformed
```

I have a working example [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/play/blob/master/matplotlib-flask/app.py) of a robust way to handle matplotlib dynamically. The general idea is

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot_png():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    draw(ax)
    return fig_response(fig)

def fig_response(fig):
    """Turn a matplotlib Figure into Flask response"""
    img_bytes = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img_bytes)
    img_bytes.seek(0)
    return send_file(img_bytes, mimetype='image/png')
```

where you supply `draw()`. Take a look at my example, though, since there are some cache headers you'll want to add.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I still don't see how could I send the parameters through the route.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. I've also modified my original question in order to make it more clear.