# Display a plotly choropleth inside a html page which is rendered using flask

Tags: python, html, flask, plotly-python

I'm currently using the code given below to develop a [choropleth map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) using plotly. I want to embed this figure inside an HTML page which I'm rendering using a flask. Are there any solutions for this?

```py
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
fig = px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)
fig.show()
```

Comment: This page shows an example of converting figure to HTML, maybe it can help you : https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Comment: [Have look here](https://www.google.com/search?q=plotly+web+page+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268133/generate-image-on-the-fly-using-flask-and-matplotlib/53268562#53268562 (and a complete working example: https://github.com/davewsmith/play/tree/master/matplotlib-flask)

Answer (score 0):

If you are already running a Flask server, you might consider serving the figure via Dash,

```
import dash
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc
from flask import Flask


def my_figure():
    df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
    return px.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                         color="lifeExp",  # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                         hover_name="country",  # column to add to hover information
                         color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma)


# Assume this is your current flask server.
server = Flask(__name__)
# Create a dash app that binds to your current server with some prefix.
app = dash.Dash(server=server, routes_pathname_prefix="/my_figure/")
# Generate the figure you need.
app.layout = dcc.Graph(figure=my_figure(), style={"width": "100%", "height": "100vh"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

With this code, the figure is accessible at `http://127.0.0.1:8050/my_figure/`. Depending on your needs, you could then do the actual embedding with e.g. an iframe.